# Would it be possible to reduce vertical space between the highlighted assertions by preserving the 'flalign environment'?

Tags: spacing, align

NOTE:--- I can reduce the vertical space by using `\phantom` in the `eqnarray environment,` but, if I use it, **an unnecessary horizontal space** occurs between the symbol of equality and the mathematical statement as in the (02) figure. Hence I want to preserve the `flalign environment.`

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
 \newcommand\commenteq[1]{\text{\footnotesize(#1)}}


\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
E&=\times(\times a^{3}b^{2}c^{5})\times (\times a^{5}b^{6}c^{11})\div (\times a^{4}b^{3}c^{15}).&
\\
&=\times a^{3}\times b^{2}\times c^{5}\times a^{5}\times b^{6}\times c^{11}\div a^{4}\div b^{3}\div c^{15};\,\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of association for multiplication and division)}&
\\
&=\times a^{5}\times a^{3}\div a^{4}\times b^{6}\times b^{2}\div b^{3}\times c^{11}\times c^{5}\div c^{15};\,\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}&
\\
E&=\times [\times (\times a^{5}\times a^{3})\div a^{4}]\times [\times (\times b^{6}\times b^{2})\div b^{3}]\times [\times (\times c^{4}\times c^{3})\div c^{5}];\,\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of association for multiplication and division)}&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Figure (02).
[image]

Comment: please always post complete examples not just fragments that can not be run. Don't you get an error from the above? \(short)intertext only makes sense at the start of a line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I ask for a sincere apology.   I re-corrected my mistake.

Comment: No even after the edit the example just makes `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \begin{flalign*}
                     
? ` and no output.

Comment: oh actually an error message is avoided (although the markup is incorrect), If you omit `\\ ` before `\intertext` amsmath does this (from its code comments): %    If current mode is not vmode, the most likely reason is that the
%    writer forgot the \cn{\\} that is supposed to precede
%    \cn{intertext}. All right, then, let's try adding it our ownself.
%    But, to be slightly careful: \cn{\\} does a futurelet, and it's

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You must be so absolutely furious. I missed placing `begin{document}`and `end{document}`.   It will not happen next time.  Thank you very much for making the necessary improvements.  To-day, I read a PDF on LaTeX symbols authored by you.

Comment: not even a bit cross, just pointing out the example didn't work as posted. (I was expecting it to give a tex error but actually it didn't, as I saw from the code Zarko posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
E & = \times(\times a^{3}b^{2}c^{5})\times 
        (\times a^{5}b^{6}c^{11})\div (\times a^{4}b^{3}c^{15}).  &   \\
  & = \times a^{3}\times b^{2}\times c^{5}\times a^{5}\times b^{6}\times c^{11}\div a^{4}\div b^{3}\div c^{15};\,
%
\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of association for multiplication and division)}
%
&=\times a^{5}\times a^{3}\div a^{4}\times b^{6}\times b^{2}\div b^{3}\times c^{11}\times c^{5}\div c^{15};\,
%
\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}
E&=\times [\times (\times a^{5}\times a^{3})\div a^{4}]\times [\times (\times b^{6}\times b^{2})\div b^{3}]\times [\times (\times c^{4}\times c^{3})\div c^{5}];\,
%
\shortintertext{\hspace{+2em}(The law of association for multiplication and division)}&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Extra verrtical space you force with `& \\` after `\shortintertext`.

Answer (score 1):

I find the math notation *very* strange. Anyway, you're using improperly `\shortintertext` and it's easier than that:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\pad}{\hphantom{={}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flalign*}
E&=
  \times(\times a^{3}b^{2}c^{5})\times (\times a^{5}b^{6}c^{11})
  \div (\times a^{4}b^{3}c^{15}).&
\\
&=
  \times a^{3}\times b^{2}\times c^{5}\times a^{5}\times b^{6}\times c^{11}
  \div a^{4}\div b^{3}\div c^{15};&
\\
&\pad
  \text{(The law of association for multiplication and division)}&
\\
&=
  \times a^{5}\times a^{3}\div a^{4}\times b^{6}\times b^{2}\div b^{3}\times c^{11}
  \times c^{5}\div c^{15};&
\\
&\pad
  \text{(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}&
\\
E&=
  \times [\times (\times a^{5}\times a^{3})\div a^{4}]
  \times [\times (\times b^{6}\times b^{2})\div b^{3}]
  \times [\times (\times c^{4}\times c^{3})\div c^{5}];&
\\
&\pad
  \text{(The law of association for multiplication and division)}&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!   I had NO previous acquaintance with `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\newcommand{\pad}{\hphantom{={}}}.`   Thank you very much for the improvement.   Could you please assert the which notation makes a peculiar appearance to you?

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa the use of \times as a prefix (especially when used as an infix in the same expression) looks very strange, as do the trailing semicolons

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa `lipsum` is just for getting mock text and showing the alignment. I've never seen `(\times a^5\times a^3)`, that is, the `\times` sign used in prefix form (unless Polish notation is employed, which is not the case here).